# Responsive nav not appearing as intended

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to create a responsive nav bar, but I am coming across issues making it appear in the way intended.

Here is an image of how it looks when **window is maximized**:

[image]

Here is an image when the **window is resized**:

[image]

Here is an image of what I want the page to **look and function** like:

[image]

**Issues**:

- As the images show, the `header` currently shows the links "stretches, mobility" etc, when I want it to display "Join / Log In" etc (image 3).
- When `menu`is clicked, I want the nav to dynamically display the other links.

Here is what I have tried so far: https://jsfiddle.net/hudnybux/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think I got it to look almost exactly like your screenshots. One of the main things I had to do was move your `nav-trigger` up within html.

```
<div id="header-main">
    <div id="nav-trigger"><span>Menu</span></div>
    <nav id="main-navigation" role="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Stretches</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mobility</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Posture</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <!--<nav id="nav-mobile"></nav>-->
</div>
```

Technically you no longer need `nav-mobile` nav. I also fixed your caret triangle next to "menu". It needed a height and width of `0`.

```
width: 0;
height: 0;
```

**Edit:**

I have revisited my solution. Just as a suggestion, I am recommending `css transitions` instead of jQuery `slideDown` and `slideUp`. You were already applying a class and that is all we need to create dynamic animations. jQuery's methods apply the styles inline and frankly leave you with less flexibility.

https://jsfiddle.net/qnco3x7e/8/

Comment: Hello Serg, I want to thank you for your working solution! I can see from the fiddle that it not only works, but works exactly as I want it. However, for some reason, I cannot seem to emulate the results. I have used the exact same code (only addition I made was to add a red border around `#nav-trigger` to see what the div occupies), but for some reason the links do not appear dynamically on `menu` click. Here is my current code: https://jsfiddle.net/0ngL329q/ . I would appreciate it if you could see where I am going wrong, even though I am working with your code (which clearly works).

Comment: @Freddy you just haven't loaded jQuery in your fiddle. You can include it as external file or turn on jQuery by clicking on JavaScript with gear icon, and choosing a framework from the list.

Comment: Ah! completely forgot about loading JQuery. Everything works superbly now, many thanks to you Serg!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add another `media query`

```
@media all and (max-width: 460px) {
  nav#main-navigation li {
    display:block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fafafa;
  }
}
```

Comment: That does seem to neaten up the 'header' slightly, although it still creates a new row to show the link. But i'll take it! Slow progress is better than no progress, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Writing others' code for them is not in the spirit of Stack Overflow, but, as I prefer teaching by showing and not telling, I went ahead and did the task for you. Observe how I changed your implementation and learn as much as you can!

### The Strategy

- Use the same HTML markup for the main menu (Stretches, Mobility, Posture) on both large and small screen widths, instead of using JavaScript to duplicate it in two places.
- Use the same CSS for both menus as a starting point; in the media query for small screen sizes, change the main menu to be horizontal
- Show everything by default; use `display: none` only on screen sizes you don't want to show something on.

### [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/darrylyeo/n3ym4m64/3/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#main-nav-mobile-trigger span").click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("open");
        if ($(this).hasClass("open")) {
            $("#main-nav").addClass("open").slideDown(250);
        } else {
            $("#main-nav").removeClass("open").slideUp(250);
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.pageOverlay {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


/******************/

nav {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    /*NAV COLOUR*/
    padding: 10px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
 text-align: center;
}

nav ul li a {
    color: #a4a4a5;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    color: black;
}

nav ul {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 2px;
}

nav li:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}

nav a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}


/****************************************************************/


/* Menu CSS which pops up when window is resized */

#main-nav-mobile-trigger {
    text-align: center;
}

#main-nav-mobile-trigger span {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#main-nav-mobile-trigger span:after {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 10px;
    content: "";
    border-left: solid 10px transparent;
    border-top: solid 10px #e3e3e3;
    border-right: solid 10px transparent;
}

#main-nav-mobile-trigger span:hover {
    background-color: #e3e3e3;
}

#main-nav-mobile-trigger span.open:after {
    border-left: solid 10px transparent;
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: solid 10px #fff;
    border-right: solid 10px transparent;
}

@media all and (min-width: 901px) {
    #top-nav {
        text-align: right;
    }
    #main-nav {
        text-align: left;
    }
    #main-nav-mobile-trigger {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media all and (max-width: 900px) {
    #main-nav:not(.open) {
     display: none;
    }
    #main-nav ul {
        display: block;
 }
    #main-nav li {
        display: block;
        border-bottom: solid 1px #e3e3e3;
    }
    #main-nav li:last-child {
        border-bottom: none;
    }
    #main-nav a {
        padding: 10px 30px;
    }
    #main-nav a:hover {
        background-color: #e3e3e3;
        color: #fff;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pageOverlay">
    <nav id="top-nav" role="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Join / Log In</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div id="main-nav-mobile-trigger"><span>Menu</span></div>
    <nav id="main-nav" role="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Stretches</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mobility</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Posture</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
<!-- pageOverlay closed-->
```

### The HTML

- I removed your container `<div>`s (`#header` and `#header-main`), as they serve no purpose as far as layout is concerned.
- There are now only three parts to the header area. In order they are:

  - `#top-nav` - Join/Login, Help, Shop
  - `#main-nav-mobile-trigger` - MENU button
  - `#main-nav` - Stretches, Mobility, Posture

### The JavaScript

- When the MENU button (`#main-nav-mobile-trigger span`) is clicked:

  - Toggle its `.open` class.
  - If it has the `.open` class,

    - Add `#main-nav`'s `.open` class.
  - Otherwise,

    - Remove `#main-nav`'s `.open` class.

### The CSS

- You had duplicates of the styling rules for each horizontal menu (formerly `#nav-main` and `#main-navigation`, which are very easy to confuse). These are now combined into one set of rules under the more general selector, `nav`. Additionally, their `text-align` is set to `center` by default (the desired alignment on small screen widths).
- For big screen widths (`@media all and (min-width: 901px)`):

  - Align `#top-nav` to the right and `#main-nav` to the left.
  - Hide the MENU button.
- For small screen widths (`@media all and (max-width: 900px)`):

  - If `#main-nav` doesn't have the `.open` class, hide it.
  - Display the menu items in `#main-nav` horizontally.

---

I hope this helps you. Best of luck with your future adventures in front-end development!

Comment: You used the wrong selector for the Menu button, and you should only toggle the "open" class after doing the check.

Comment: How did I use the wrong selector? What is wrong with my current logic?

Comment: Didn't mean it in an attacking way :). In your first fiddle you set a listener on nav-trigger but that element doesn't exist. Nothing wrong with the logic :).

Comment: Ah, found the source of confusion. I forgot to update to the [most recent JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/darrylyeo/n3ym4m64/3/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox css properties. It's very powerfull. http://www.alsacreations.com/tuto/lire/1493-css3-flexbox-layout-module.html